# Recyclerview is not updating when shared prefrence item added

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i want to safe this data in shared preferences to recycler-view but it's not working as intended

the recycler view is not updating, instead if you close the app an reopen you see the inserted item

**here is my code **

```
    val list= mutableListOf<NoteModel>()


    var sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE)

    var editor = sharedPref.edit()


    myAdapter = RecyclerviewAdepter(list)
    binding.recyclerView.adapter = myAdapter

        binding.btAdd.setOnClickListener {

            val text = binding.editText.text.toString()
            val isChecked = binding.isCheckbox.isChecked

            editor.apply {
                putString("text", text)
                putBoolean("isChecked", isChecked)
                apply()
            }


    }


    var title = sharedPref.getString("text", null)
    var isChecked1 = sharedPref.getBoolean("isChecked",false)


    var todo = NoteModel(title!!,isChecked1)

    list.add(todo)

    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    myAdapter.notifyItemInserted(list.size -1)

}
```

Comment: There is nothing in your code that listens to changes in Preferences.

Comment: but i have adde notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: You are adding something to `list` and then you try to tell `myAdapter` that data set has changed. `myAdapter`s data haven't change at all. You have changed the original `list`. You have to update data that is in the `myAdapter` itself.

Comment: sorry but how can i do that if i my i ask

Answer (score 1):

Hi idont much but it works for me. If you want to update only Recyclerview
fragment, adapter with xml
inside adapter a method that add item and inside

```
public void updateData(List<Notification> contacts) {
    this.notificationList = contacts;
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

is show a warning notifyDataSetChanged but works

or u can use DiffUtis instead o notifyDataSetChanged

--
DiffUtils approach

https://gist.github.com/rogergcc/dfbd35cd74ebf7bb7052f1d2cbb1a592

Comment: i am trying to update  myAdapter.update(list). but the update is red

Comment: hi what measn red?  
something linke list not show in recyclereiw?

or the code in in red color like incorrect

Comment: update method will be in adapter

Answer (score 0):

Your click listener updates only data in the preferences storage, but not the list rendered on the screen. So, you should notify the RV:

```
 binding.btAdd.setOnClickListener {
     // do data operations:
     val text = binding.editText.text.toString()
     val isChecked = binding.isCheckbox.isChecked
     editor.apply {
         putString("text", text)
         putBoolean("isChecked", isChecked)
         apply()
     }

     // if you use list not as a reference, than update it in the adapter
     // (sth like myAdapter.updateList(list)

     // anyway, notify:
    myAdapter.notifyItemInserted(list.size -1)
}
```

Comment: unfortunately its still not updating and adding to the recycler view but when i reopen the app you can see the added item but its when i use " myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()" if i use " myAdapter.notifyItemInserted(list.size -1)"   the app crashes